# can I use silverlight to overcome activex issues in chrome?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, entity-framework, google-chrome, activex

I have a phone caller id device. I want to record calling numbers to database. I used javascript and Activex but that only works in IE. I am using MVC and EF.

Is it possible to use Silverlight and embed it to my web application project so that the silverlight project can access to database and record the phone number.

If it is possible, can you show me a simple example pls?
(i created a project on Silverlight but cannot add dlls(caller id device SDKs) to references.)

Comment: Sure, you can use Silverlight, but you'll need a WCF service layer to handle the database stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't explain why you are using ActiveX so I assume the control is able to provide an interface to your hardware phone caller ID device.

Silverlight could possibly solve your problem. However, if you have to call native code (e.g. a COM object to access the phone ID device) you will have to run the Silverlight application as a [Trusted Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). In general this requires the application to be run Out Of Browser (OOB). This makes the browser only be a vehicle for installing the OOB Silverlight application.

You will also have to create a web service interface allowing your Silverlight application to interact with the database. You cannot just add references to Entity Framework in your Silverlight project and then access the database directly. However, using [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services) it is reasonable simple to connect your Silverligt application to Entity Framework hosted in IIS.

Comment: thanks for information. I made a mistake and edited question. What i want to add is not EF DLLs but device DLLs. How does silverlight connect to device without using device dlls(SDKs)?

Comment: @gesirdekatwork: In Silverlight 5 you can use P/Invoke, but it has to run as a trusted application. More is explained in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "ActiveX for Chrome" extension?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgllffgicojgllpmdbemgglaponefajn

Comment: i tried but it did not work...    
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'start'